# Attempting to convert a string to an int (C#)

Tags: c#, string, int

I'm trying to learn the basics to c# coding (or any code for that matter). I'm not understanding how to take user input and put it into a string that I can later use as an integer. I thought I could write it like

```
string baseOfTriange = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine));
```

but it's not working. I've also tried float thinking maybe that was it, however, I'm just lost on the concept. This is what I have so far, I just can't figure out how to convert a string to an int. Thanks for any help.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // area of a triangle = base(height)/2

    Console.WriteLine("Welcome, enter your triangle dimensions. ");
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.Write("What is the base of the triangle? ");
    string baseOfTriangle = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("You answered, " + baseOfTriangle + ". ");

    Console.Write("What is your height of the triangle? ");
    string heightOfTriangle = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("You answered, " + heightOfTriangle + ". ");

    Console.WriteLine("The area of the triangle is " + (baseOfTriangle * heightOfTriangle / 2));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: int baseOfTriange = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine));

Comment: Does this code compile? or do you get exception at runtime?

Comment: By replacing string with int, I was able to run it correctly. I couldn't convert the string to an integer and store it in a string variable. Sorry, I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're getting a compile time error because of the following line:

```
string baseOfTriangle = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

The return type of `int.Parse` is `int` but your trying to assign it to a variable of type `string`. Change the type of `baseOfTriangle` and `heightOfTriangle` to `int` and that will solve your problem.

```
int baseOfTriangle = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
^^^
```

Also, you probably want a floating point answer. Otherwise `1*1/2` will give you an answer of 0.  Change it to `baseOfTriangle * heightOfTriangle / 2.0`. Or better yet use `double` and `double.Parse`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the C# Programming Guide:  How to: Convert a String to a Number:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx

Also look at the TryParse methods for most built-in number types for c#.  For example, int32.TryParse():
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("What is the base of the triangle? ");
    int baseOfTriangle = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("What is your height of the triangle? ");
    int heightOfTriangle = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("The area of the triangle is {0}", (baseOfTriangle * heightOfTriangle) / 2);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so I'm assuming the {0} was what I was missing - what would I look up to learn more about that? I just started yesterday and I'm sure I'll learn more in class, just trying to mess around with it and learn more for myself.

Comment: Most important thing was that you were reading a string, parsing it to an int, and then trying to store it back as a string. Later on, you were multiplying 2 strings etc (:O) and then using string concatenation (+ sign), to print your answer. `{0}` is just a better way of formatting strings for various reasons, specially when output you want to print is of type other than string. See following link on String Formatting - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx Note that it is applicable for formatting strings in many places in .Net, not just `String.Format`

Answer (score -1):

The usual method to convert to int is with Convert.ToInt32()